# Tensorflowjs TypeError: Unknown op 'SimpleMLCreateModelResource'

Tags: node.js, machine-learning, tensorflow.js, tfjs-node, tensorflow-decision-forests

I am having an issue with tensoflowjs where it looks like everything loads properly, but when I go to make a prediction it throws an error. This is a decision forest that was trained in python using "tfdf.keras.RandomForestModel(tuner=tuner, verbose=0,                             task=tfdf.keras.Task.REGRESSION)" and saved to savedModel. It is then converted  using,

```
!mkdir model
# convert
!tensorflowjs_converter \
    --input_format=tf_saved_model \
    ./tf_forest \
    ./model
# zip
!zip -r model.zip model
```

and then loaded into a nodejs script. I am unsure what is causing my issue so any insight would be great. Thanks!

Here is the node script

```
import * as tf from '@tensorflow/tfjs';
import * as tfn from '@tensorflow/tfjs-node';

const handler = tfn.io.fileSystem("./model/model.json");
const model = await tf.loadGraphModel(handler);

var data = [49,3186.21,489.66,92.99,0,192,151.2,17119.633333333335,98.82,20.31];

console.log(typeof data);

model.predict(data).print();
```

This is the error that is thrown.

```
2023-01-18 08:56:59.444604: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:193] This TensorFlow binary
is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN) to use the following CPU instructions in
performance-critical operations:  AVX2 FMA
To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
object
/home/brad/scikit.js/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-converter/dist/tf-converter.node.js:29610
                 throw TypeError("Unknown op '".concat(node.op, "'. File an issue at ") +
                  ^

TypeError: Unknown op 'SimpleMLCreateModelResource'. File an issue at
https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs/issues so we can add it, or register a custom execution with
tf.registerOp()
     at /home/brad/scikit.js/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-converter/dist/tf-converter.node.js:29610:23
     at executeOp (/home/brad/scikit.js/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-converter/dist/tf-
converter.node.js:29614:7)
     at /home/brad/scikit.js/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-converter/dist/tf-converter.node.js:30150:35
     at /home/brad/scikit.js/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-core/dist/tf-core.node.js:4506:22
     at Engine.scopedRun (/home/brad/scikit.js/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-core/dist/tf-
core.node.js:4516:23)
     at Engine.tidy (/home/brad/scikit.js/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-core/dist/tf-
core.node.js:4505:21)
    at Object.tidy (/home/brad/scikit.js/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-core/dist/tf-
core.node.js:8053:19)
     at GraphExecutor.execute (/home/brad/scikit.js/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-converter/dist/tf-
converter.node.js:30130:20)
     at GraphModel.executeInitializerGraph (/home/brad/scikit.js/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-
converter/dist/tf-converter.node.js:31016:37)
     at GraphModel.execute (/home/brad/scikit.js/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-converter/dist/tf-
converter.node.js:31064:52)

Node.js v19.4.0
```

Here is the package.json.

```
 {
  "dependencies": {
    "@tensorflow/tfjs": "^4.2.0",
    "@tensorflow/tfjs-node": "^4.2.0",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "particle-api-js": "^9.4.1"
  },
  "name": "Rfr-Test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "main": "App.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "description": ""
}
```

I have have tried both loadGraphModel and LoadLayesModel. both come up with different errors. The loadGraphModel error is above and LoadLayersModel returns the error below.

```
2023-01-18 09:06:36.329506: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:193] This TensorFlow binary 
is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN) to use the following CPU instructions in 
performance-critical operations:  AVX2 FMA
To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
/home/brad/scikit.js/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-layers/dist/tf-layers.node.js:276
        var _this = _super.call(this, message) || this;
                           ^

ValueError: layer: Improper config format: {"node":[{"name":"blue","op":"Placeholder","attr":{"dtype":
{"type":"DTFLOAT"},"shape":{"shape":{"dim":[{"size":"-1"}]}}}},{"name":"cct","op":"Placeholder","attr":
{"shape":{"shape":{"dim":[{"size":"-1"}]}},"dtype":{"type":"DTFLOAT"}}},
{"name":"clear","op":"Placeholder","attr":{"dtype":{"type":"DTFLOAT"},"shape":{"shape":{"dim":
[{"size":"-1"}]}}}},{"name":"gain","op":"Placeholder","attr":{"dtype":{"type":"DTFLOAT"},"shape":
{"shape":{"dim":[{"size":"-1"}]}}}},{"name":"green","op":"Placeholder","attr":{"dtype":
{"type":"DTFLOAT"},"shape":{"shape":{"dim":[{"size":"-1"}]}}}}, 
{"name":"integration","op":"Placeholder","attr":{"shape":{"shape":{"dim":[{"size":"-1"}]}},"dtype":
{"type":"DTFLOAT"}}},{"name":"lux","op":"Placeholder","attr":{"shape":{"shape":{"dim":
[{"size":"-1"}]}},"dtype":{"type":"DTFLOAT"}}},{"name":"minutes","op":"Placeholder","attr":{"shape":
{"shape":{"dim":[{"size":"-1"}]}},"dtype":{"type":"DTFLOAT"}}},{"name":"red","op":"Placeholder","attr":
{"dtype":{"type":"DTFLOAT"},"shape":{"shape":{"dim":[{"size":"-1"}]}}}},
{"name":"temp","op":"Placeholder","attr":{"shape":{"shape":{"dim":[{"size":"-1"}]}},"dtype":
{"type":"DTFLOAT"}}},{"name":"unknown","op":"Placeholder","attr":{"dtype":
{"type":"DTRESOURCE"},"shape":{"shape":{}}}},
{"name":"Func/StatefulPartitionedCall/random_forest_model_1/StatefulPartitionedCall/input_control_node/_13" 
    ,"op":"NoOp","input":     
["^blue","^cct","^unknown","^clear","^green","^gain","^integration","^lux","^minutes","^red","^temp"],"attr":{"HasManualControlDependencies":{"b":true}}},{"name":"StatefulPartitionedCall/random_forest_model_1/StatefulPartitionedCall/stack","op":"Pack","input":["blue","cct","clear","green","gain","integration","lux","minutes","red","temp","^Func/StatefulPartitionedCall/randomForestModel1/StatefulPartitionedCall/inputControlNode/13"],"attr":{"T":{"type":"DTFLOAT"},"axis":{"i":"1"},"N":{"i":"10"}}},{"name":"StatefulPartitionedCall/random_forest_model_1/StatefulPartitionedCall/Const","op":"Const","input":["^Func/StatefulPartitionedCall/randomForestModel1/StatefulPartitionedCall/inputControlNode/13"],"attr":{"value":{"tensor":{"dtype":"DTFLOAT","tensorShape":{"dim":[{},{}]}}},"dtype":{"type":"DTFLOAT"}}},{"name":"StatefulPartitionedCall/random_forest_model_1/StatefulPartitionedCall/Const_1","op":"Const","input":["^Func/StatefulPartitionedCall/randomForestModel1/StatefulPartitionedCall/inputControlNode/13"],"attr":{"dtype":{"type":"DTINT32"},"value":{"tensor":{"dtype":"DTINT32","tensorShape":{"dim":[{},{}]}}}}},{"name":"StatefulPartitionedCall/random_forest_model_1/StatefulPartitionedCall/RaggedConstant/values","op":"Const","input":["^Func/StatefulPartitionedCall/randomForestModel1/StatefulPartitionedCall/inputControlNode/13"],"attr":{"value":{"tensor":{"dtype":"DTINT32","tensorShape":{"dim":[{}]}}},"dtype":{"type":"DTINT32"}}},{"name":"StatefulPartitionedCall/random_forest_model_1/StatefulPartitionedCall/RaggedConstant/Const","op":"Const","input":  "^Func/StatefulPartitionedCall/randomForestModel1/StatefulPartitionedCall/inputControlNode/13"],"attr":{"value":{"tensor":{"dtype":"DTINT64","tensorShape":{"dim":[{"size":"1"}]}}},"dtype":{"type":"DTINT64"}}},{"name":"StatefulPartitionedCall/random_forest_model_1/StatefulPartitionedCall/RaggedConstant/Const_1","op":"Const","input":["^Func/StatefulPartitionedCall/randomForestModel1/StatefulPartitionedCall/inputControlNode/13"],"attr":{"dtype":{"type":"DTINT64"},"value":{"tensor":{"dtype":"DTINT64","tensorShape":{"dim":[{"size":"1"}]}}}}},{"name":"StatefulPartitionedCall/random_forest_model_1/StatefulPartitionedCall/inference_op","op":"SimpleMLInferenceOpWithHandle","input":["StatefulPartitionedCall/randomForestModel1/StatefulPartitionedCall/stack","StatefulPartitionedCall/randomForestModel1/StatefulPartitionedCall/Const","StatefulPartitionedCall/randomForestModel1/StatefulPartitionedCall/Const1","StatefulPartitionedCall/randomForestModel1/StatefulPartitionedCall/RaggedConstant/values","StatefulPartitionedCall/randomForestModel1/StatefulPartitionedCall/RaggedConstant/Const","StatefulPartitionedCall/randomForestModel1/StatefulPartitionedCall/RaggedConstant/Const1","unknown"],"attr":{"HasManualControlDependencies":{"b":true},"denseOutputDim":{"i":"1"}}},{"name":"Identity","op":"Identity","input":["StatefulPartitionedCall/randomForestModel1/StatefulPartitionedCall/inferenceOp"],"attr":{"T":{"type":"DTFLOAT"}}}],"library":{},"versions":{"producer":1286}}.
'className' and 'config' must set.
    at new ValueError (/home/brad/scikit.js/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-layers/dist/tf-layers.node.js:276:28)
    at deserializeKerasObject (/home/brad/scikit.js/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-layers/dist/tf-layers.node.js:600:19)
    at deserialize (/home/brad/scikit.js/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-layers/dist/tf-layers.node.js:19671:12)
    at /home/brad/scikit.js/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-layers/dist/tf-layers.node.js:25202:29
    at step (/home/brad/scikit.js/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-layers/dist/tf-layers.node.js:162:27)
    at Object.next (/home/brad/scikit.js/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-layers/dist/tf-layers.node.js:111:53)
    at fulfilled (/home/brad/scikit.js/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-layers/dist/tf-layers.node.js:92:28)

Node.js v19.4.0
```

Answer (score 2):

Update: Tensorflow Decision Forests models are now compatible with Tensorflow.js. Check out [this tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/decision_forests/tf_df_in_tf_js) for detailed instructions on how to get a TF-DF model running with TF.js.

Based on the error message, it looks like your model was trained with [Tensorflow Decision Forests](https://github.com/tensorflow/decision-forests) (TF-DF). Tensorflow Decision Forests uses some Tensorflow ops (e.g., `SimpleMLCreateModelResource`) that are not included in the main Tensorflow and are also missing from Tensorflow.js.

The good news is that the TF-DF team and the TF.js team are actively working on support for TF-DF models in Tensorflow.js. This work is ongoing but has not  landed in the main branch at this time.

Full Disclosure: I'm one of the authors of Tensorflow Decision Forests.

Comment: The same error apparently prevents tensorflow-onnx from converting TFDF models to ONNX.